# Plotting progress in cplex optimization

Tags: c++, cplex

I would like to able to plot the progress of a MIP solved by cplex. Specifically I would like to plot lower and upper bounds as functions of cpu-time. But copying an pasting from the node log does not seem to be a smartest way of proceeding. Is it possible to access these information and to print them out/to file during the optimization?
I am using the concert technology C++ interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "MIP info callback" using the API routine `CPXsetinfocallbackfunc` or its analogue in Concert.

(Copying-and-pasting the log it dumps to the terminal is perfectly fine for getting a rough idea of what's going on, but be aware that the results can be highly variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are what you are looking for. You can find a nice introduction here:

http://eaton.math.rpi.edu/cplex90html/usrcplex/callbacks.html